# sftp write operation atomicity with Python

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, atomic, pysftp

When appending lines to a remote file via SFTP with `pysftp`:

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection('192.168.0.2', username='root', password='') as sftp:    
    with sftp.cd('/home/www/test'):
        with sftp.open('test.txt', 'a+') as f:
            for i in range(100):
                s = (("%04d" % i).encode()*10000) + b'\n'  # 40'001 bytes
                f.write(s)
```

if I terminate the process in the middle of the operation, sometimes (if I'm lucky), the whole line `s` is written on the distant file.

On other cases, the last line is truncated in the middle, at the time the process has been interrupted.

**Is there a way to make the SFTP `f.write(s)` operation atomic?** i.e. either it fails in the middle, then nothing is written, or it succeeds and the full 40'001 byte-line is written?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.  First of all, in order for it to be possible at all, the remote system's `write(2)` syscall would have to guarantee that, and POSIX does not require that behavior.  There are many reasons a write may be non-atomic, such as if the remote disk is full and you can only write part of the data to disk, or if the remote user has a quota and your full write would exceed that.

Additionally, you're trying to write over 40 kB over a network connection, and it's likely that doesn't fit in one packet.  Consequently, it wouldn't make sense for any network software to write a packet that large.

If it's important to you to write a file completely or not at all, you can write to another file on the same disk and then rename over the original file.  This is the way programs like Git guarantee atomic file updates.  I believe for SFTP that requires that both sides support the `posix-rename@openssh.com` extension; OpenSSH does, but I don't know if `pysftp` does, so you'd need to consult the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. *you can write to another file on the same disk and then rename over the original file*: that's what I do when sending totally new files: `sftp.put(f, 'myfile.tmp')` and `sftp.rename('myfile.tmp', 'myfile')` when it's successfully finished. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) but when appending (open in `a+` mode) to an existing remote 2 GB file, I can't duplicate the file to `myfile.tmp` each time I want to append 100 KB to it, delete the original `myfile`, rename `myfile.tmp` to `myfile`, this would be highly unefficient to re-write 2 GB to append only 100KB.